# Unable to trace a method with a parameter by using MethodInstrumentationModule

Tags: open-telemetry, byte-buddy

I am unable to trace a method with one parameter ( `com.my.processor.MyEvent` ) in my class (`com.my.processor.BlobProcessor`) implementing `java.util.function.Consumer` by using extension `MethodInstrumentationModule` but this extension works well for my own method without any input parameter. The line below is my configuration:

`otel.instrumentation.methods.include=com.my.processor.BlobProcessor[accept]`

Can someone help me about it?

You help will be appreciated.

In addition, jdk version is

> java version "17.0.4.1" 2022-08-18 LTS Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
> (build 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build
> 17.0.4.1+1-LTS-2, mixed mode, sharing)

Opentelemenrty: `opentelemetry-javaagent - version: 1.30.0`